Trying to perform a calculation using previous values in a column
Using the below data frame as a rough example of what I'm trying to do: in column b, I have the correct values when times = 0 but I want to code it so that the values currently blank ("") will use the value from the column above minus the value of a in that row.
df <- data.frame(ages = c(20,20,20,20,
                         21,21,21,21,
                         22,22,22,22,
                         23,23,23,23),
                 year = c(2023,2024,2025,2026,
                          2023,2024,2025,2026,
                          2023,2024,2025,2026,
                          2023,2024,2025,2026),
                 times = c(0,1,2,3,
                       0,1,2,3,
                       0,1,2,3,
                       0,1,2,3),
                 a = c(-0.1,-0.26,-0.39,-0.48,
                       -0.05,-0.11,-0.23,-0.68,
                       -0.02,-0.13,-0.28,-0.33,
                       -0.01,-0.44,-0.5,-0.52),
                 b = c(1,"","","",
                       2,"","","",
                       3,"","","",
                       4,"","",""))

I have tried some dplyr::mutate() and lag functions but keep getting errors.

Welcome to R! Have you noticed that you are mixing numerics and character in th b colums? Try to replace the "" with NA. You might want to read a little to be more familiar with R: https://r4ds.hadley.nz/workflow-basics. Otherwise, you can try something like: df %>%  mutate(b2 = b) %>% fill(b2)%>%   mutate(b3 = if_else(is.na(b), dplyr::lag(b2) - a, b2))

v1
For X=df:
> transform(X, b=ave(replace(strtoi(b), i, -a[i<-b==""]), ages, FUN=cumsum))
   ages year times     a    b
1    20 2023     0 -0.10 1.00
2    20 2024     1 -0.26 1.26
3    20 2025     2 -0.39 1.65
4    20 2026     3 -0.48 2.13
5    21 2023     0 -0.05 2.00
6    21 2024     1 -0.11 2.11
7    21 2025     2 -0.23 2.34
8    21 2026     3 -0.68 3.02
9    22 2023     0 -0.02 3.00
10   22 2024     1 -0.13 3.13
11   22 2025     2 -0.28 3.41
12   22 2026     3 -0.33 3.74
13   23 2023     0 -0.01 4.00
14   23 2024     1 -0.44 4.44
15   23 2025     2 -0.50 4.94
16   23 2026     3 -0.52 5.46

v0
> do.call(rbind, lapply(split(X, X$ages), transform, b = cumsum(c(b[1L], -a[-1L]))))
      ages year times     a    b
20.1    20 2023     0 -0.10 1.00
20.2    20 2024     1 -0.26 1.26
20.3    20 2025     2 -0.39 1.65
20.4    20 2026     3 -0.48 2.13
21.5    21 2023     0 -0.05 2.00
21.6    21 2024     1 -0.11 2.11
21.7    21 2025     2 -0.23 2.34
21.8    21 2026     3 -0.68 3.02
22.9    22 2023     0 -0.02 3.00
22.10   22 2024     1 -0.13 3.13
22.11   22 2025     2 -0.28 3.41
22.12   22 2026     3 -0.33 3.74
23.13   23 2023     0 -0.01 4.00
23.14   23 2024     1 -0.44 4.44
23.15   23 2025     2 -0.50 4.94
23.16   23 2026     3 -0.52 5.46

# or

> by(X, ~ages, transform, b=cumsum(c(b[1L], -a[-1L])), ages=NULL) |> array2DF()
    ages year times     a    b
1     20 2023     0 -0.10 1.00
1.1   20 2024     1 -0.26 1.26
1.2   20 2025     2 -0.39 1.65
1.3   20 2026     3 -0.48 2.13
2     21 2023     0 -0.05 2.00
2.1   21 2024     1 -0.11 2.11
2.2   21 2025     2 -0.23 2.34
2.3   21 2026     3 -0.68 3.02
3     22 2023     0 -0.02 3.00
3.1   22 2024     1 -0.13 3.13
3.2   22 2025     2 -0.28 3.41
3.3   22 2026     3 -0.33 3.74
4     23 2023     0 -0.01 4.00
4.1   23 2024     1 -0.44 4.44
4.2   23 2025     2 -0.50 4.94
4.3   23 2026     3 -0.52 5.46

If you are annoyed by the appearance of the row names, add
|> `rownames<-`(NULL)

Thanks to @jay.sf for the comment.

If it really needs to be {dplyr}-syntax, do
df |> dplyr::mutate(b=cumsum(c(b[1], -a[-1])), .by=ages)
#                            or use any of the variants from above.

as @langtang pointed out.

nice approach @Friede.. you could also do this way: mutate(df, b= cumsum(c(b[1],-a[-1])),.by=ages), if you want to add a dplyr version to your answer

Thank you, @langtang. I stick to base whenever possible. But, obviously, if OP looks for  {tidyverse} syntax, this approach can be easily adapted as you have nicely shown.

Nice +1, or just pipe into \rownames<-`(NULL)`.

Change df$b to numeric, get the indices where df$b is NA, and then loop over those indices, each time updating the value in df$b:
df$b <- as.numeric(df$b)
indx = which(is.na(df$b))
for(i in indx) df[i, "b"] <- df[i-1, "b"] - df[i, "a"]

Output:
   ages year times     a    b
1    20 2023     0 -0.10 1.00
2    20 2024     1 -0.26 1.26
3    20 2025     2 -0.39 1.65
4    20 2026     3 -0.48 2.13
5    21 2023     0 -0.05 2.00
6    21 2024     1 -0.11 2.11
7    21 2025     2 -0.23 2.34
8    21 2026     3 -0.68 3.02
9    22 2023     0 -0.02 3.00
10   22 2024     1 -0.13 3.13
11   22 2025     2 -0.28 3.41
12   22 2026     3 -0.33 3.74
13   23 2023     0 -0.01 4.00
14   23 2024     1 -0.44 4.44
15   23 2025     2 -0.50 4.94
16   23 2026     3 -0.52 5.46

One can also use dplyr and Reduce as follows:
library(dplyr)

df$b <- as.numeric(df$b)

mutate(
  df, 
  b = Reduce(\(z,i) z-a[i],x=2:n(),init=b[1], accumulate = T),
  .by = ages
)

Output:
   ages year times     a    b
1    20 2023     0 -0.10 1.00
2    20 2024     1 -0.26 1.26
3    20 2025     2 -0.39 1.65
4    20 2026     3 -0.48 2.13
5    21 2023     0 -0.05 2.00
6    21 2024     1 -0.11 2.11
7    21 2025     2 -0.23 2.34
8    21 2026     3 -0.68 3.02
9    22 2023     0 -0.02 3.00
10   22 2024     1 -0.13 3.13
11   22 2025     2 -0.28 3.41
12   22 2026     3 -0.33 3.74
13   23 2023     0 -0.01 4.00
14   23 2024     1 -0.44 4.44
15   23 2025     2 -0.50 4.94
16   23 2026     3 -0.52 5.46

